# Minitoc - doesn't appear while code seems fine [Fixed]

Tags: minitoc

---

SOLUTION FOUND :

Minitoc requires for some reason to compile 4 times (and not 2) to implement the changes. Which is why it sometimes didn't work...

---

I am trying to use the minitoc package to create a minitoc at the beginning of a starred chapter (with starred sections) and I want to change the name of the minitoc from "Contents" to "Procedure".

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Procedures}

\begin{document}

\faketableofcontents

\chapter*{A}
\addstarredchapter{A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A}
\minitoc

\section*{a}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{a}

\section*{b}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{b}

\end{document}
```

And I have the following problem :

- The minitoc appears when the chapter isn't starred and without modifying the title of the minitoc. Fine !
- When I modify the chapter to chapter*, the minitoc appears, but sometimes doesn't (and I cannot figure out what are the difference in the cases, maybe several compilations ?).
- When I modify its title (mtcsettitle), the minitoc sometimes appears (same question).
- When I do both (chapter* and mtcsettitle), I cannot have the minitoc appear.

Would you have an idea of what goes wrong here ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @PhilippImhof : I have re-read them and modified the beginning of the code accordingly to MWE rules.

Comment: Actually, it was meant to be a friendly welcome message rather than a criticism, because this was your first question. I am however unable to help you with the problem you have.

Comment: Oh ! Thank you for the welcoming then :)
I finally found the solution to my issue and edited the post.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. This is not at all frowned upon on this site.